# node express-session react : server cookies not sent to client

Tags: reactjs, cookies, https, graphql, express-session

Dears,

My https client, created in React, doesn't receive the cookies created on the server (node.js app, using express-session), while calling the server graphql mutations.

Both sides are https, server running on port 443 https://localhost:443 , client on port 3000 https://localhost:3000

When I run the graphql playground end point (https://localhost:443/graphql) , the graphql tool receives the cookies.

But when I call the graphql mutations from the client, using apollo, the client receives the data, but not the cookie...

Therefore I'm assuming the issue is related to the ports that are different between server and client but I tried all configurations for the cookies parameters "sameSite" and "secure".
Whatever the combination of these 2 boolean, client never receives the cookie.

Is there any other parameter to set ?

Here is the node express-session code (session are stored in a redis store)

thks.

```
app.use(cors({ origin: 'https://localhost:3000', credentials: true }));
app.use(session({
    store,
    name: SESSION_NAME,
    secret: SESSION_SECRET,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,

    cookie: {
        maxAge: parseInt(SESSION_LIFETIME),
        sameSite: !IN_DEV,
        secure: !IN_DEV
    },
}));
```

**[EDIT - ISSUE FIXED AFTER HELP FROM Daniel Rearden]**

here is the code on server side and client side to make it fix all issues.

**Server side:**

```
//  generation sessions
app.use(session({
    store,
    name: SESSION_NAME,
    secret: SESSION_SECRET,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,

    cookie: {
        maxAge: parseInt(SESSION_LIFETIME),
        httpOnly: true,
        sameSite: true,
        secure: !IN_DEV,
    },
}));

app.use(cors({ origin: 'https://localhost:3000', credentials: true }));

// should be added to avoid CORS issue after executing the Grahql queries
res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "https://localhost:3000");
const apolloServer = new ApolloServer({
    typeDefs,
    resolvers,

    //     //  permet de tester grqphql. 
    //     //  settings permet de gerer en dev les cookies
    playground: IN_DEV ? {
        settings: { 'request.credentials': 'include' }
    } : false,
    context: ({ req, res }) => ({ req, res })
});
apolloServer.applyMiddleware({ app });
```

**client side**

```
import { ApolloClient } from 'apollo-client';
import { createHttpLink } from 'apollo-link-http'
import { InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory'
const link = createHttpLink({
    uri: "https://localhost/graphql",
    credentials: 'include'
});

export const apolloClient = new ApolloClient({
    link,
    cache: new InMemoryCache({ addTypename: false })
});
```

Comment: don't think it is duplicated. My issue is that the client doesn't receive the cookie from the server, not that it doesn't send it. As I mentioned, the playground receive it well, but not the react apps running on a different port, whereas the logs show that the session is well set while receiving the request from the client. But in the response, no cookie is sent...

Comment: You have to ensure your client is configured correctly to send and receive cookies. Specifically, the http link has to be configured with the correct credentials policy (i.e. `include`) as outlined in the referenced thread. If the same request works with Playground, that points to a client configuration issue.

Comment: You can edit your question to include your client configuration if you feel like it's right but you're still seeing the same issue.

Comment: ok will do it once got access to the code. thks

Comment: Dears, this fixed my issue thks a lot. However I had to manage also the cors issue that happened after, on server side. Have updated my post for those who will faced same issue.